# Smooth a column

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table that looks like:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),date=rep(c("2017-10-22", "2017-10-29", 
                                 "2017-11-05"),2),value=c(0,2,0,1,0,0))

dt:
id  date        value
1   2017-10-22      0
1   2017-10-29      2
1   2017-11-05      0
2   2017-10-22      1
2   2017-10-29      0
2   2017-11-05      0
```

I want to smooth out the values using the function smooth = 1/2 * value + 1/4 * (previous value) + 1/4 * (last value), with appropriate boundary conditions, ending up with something like:

```
dt:
id  date        value  smooth
1   2017-10-22      0     0.5
1   2017-10-29      2       1
1   2017-11-05      0     0.5
2   2017-10-22      1    0.75
2   2017-10-29      0    0.25
2   2017-11-05      0       0
```

I'm unsure of a good way to do this over many ids, even if I nest for loops (which I'd think is avoidable anyway). I think I want something like:

```
dates = unique(dt$date)
dt[date=dates[1],smooth := 3/4 * value + 1/4 * dt[date=dates[2],value]]

for ( i in 2:(length(dates)-1)) {
  dt[date=dates[i],smooth := 1/2 * value + 1/4 * dt[date=dates[i-1],value]+ 1/4 * dt[date=dates[i+1],value]]
}
dt[date=dates[length(dates)],smooth := 3/4 * value + 1/4 * dt[date=dates[length(dates)-1],value]]
```

But again, I'm getting messed up by having to keep the ids straight. Any advice?

Comment: In row 4 is it really 0.75? Should be 0.5 or not. And 0.75 in row 3

Comment: `dt$smooth <- 0.5 * dt$value + 0.25 * c(0, dt$value[1:nrow(dt)-1]) + 0.25 * c(dt$value[2:nrow(dt)], 0)` how about this ?

Comment: @erocoar it's a boundary condition. I don't want to decrease the magnitude of the value column, just spread it out more evenly. And your solution would work if there was only one id; the problem is having a large number of different sets in the same table.

Answer (score 1):

This might not the most efficient way to do it if you have big data but I'd use [`shift`](https://rdrr.io/cran/data.table/man/shift.html) function to create `lag` and `lead` columns and use those in the calculation

```
dt[, c("lead1", "lag1") := list(shift(value, n=1, fill=0, type="lead"), 
                                shift(value, n=1, fill=0, type="lag"))]
dt[1,  smooth := 3/4 * value + 1/4 * lag1, by = .(id)]
dt[.N, smooth := 3/4 * value + 1/4 * lead1, by = .(id)]
dt[, smooth := 1/2 * value + 1/4 * lead1 + 1/4 * lag1, by = .(id)]

> dt
   id       date value lead1 lag1 smooth
1:  1 2017-10-22     0     2    0   0.50
2:  1 2017-10-29     2     0    0   1.00
3:  1 2017-11-05     0     1    2   0.75
4:  2 2017-10-22     1     0    0   0.50
5:  2 2017-10-29     0     0    1   0.25
6:  2 2017-11-05     0     0    0   0.00
```

Comment: This is close, but it's not handling the ids properly; you can see that the 1 from id 2 has drifted into the lead1 column of id 1, resulting in the third value being .75 instead of .5 and the fourth being .5 instead of .75

Comment: Actually this is really close; you switched lead and lag, and the dt[,... line has to go before the dt[1,... and dt[.N,... , but otherwise i would think this should work. Unfortunately, it seems like having 1 and .N in the i position doesn't interact as expected with the by=id; testing it, if I just say dt[.N,value,by=.(id)] I only get the very last row out, not the 3rd and 6th rows

Comment: Assuming the dates are the same for all ids, I found a solution based on this answer. Replied with my own post below.

Answer (score 1):

Based on thecatalyst's answer above, assuming the dates are the same for all ids, I can solve this with:

```
f_date = min(dt$date)
l_date = max(dt$date)
dt[, c("lead1", "lag1") := list(shift(value, n=1, fill=0, type="lead"),   
+                                 shift(value, n=1, fill=0, type="lag"))]  
dt[, smooth := 1/2 * value + 1/4 * lead1 + 1/4 * lag1]
dt[date == f_date,smooth := 3/4*value + 1/4*lead1] 
dt[date == l_date,smooth := 3/4*value + 1/4*lag1]
```

and to clean up:

```
dt = dt[,c(-4,-5)]
```